# Pathfinding algorithm with least amount of steps

Tags: java, algorithm, path-finding

I'm looking for some kind of path finding algorithm that does not only give me the shortest path. I want to get the shortest path with the least amount of steps.

Currently I'm using [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to get the shortest path, but I'm not stuck to this.

In my example, you have to stop at certain locations, that have a specific price. So I want to get the 'cheapest' route, but I also want to stop the least amount of times.

Comment: "shortest path" already implies "path with the least amount of steps"?, or do you mean you want a path with shortest distance and minimum node traversal? Like if we have two paths with same length A->B->C->D and A->F->D you want to select second path?

Comment: Yes, thats right!

Comment: Use your same Dijkstra algorithm, but for each node keep an additional information that stores "how many steps it took to reach that node". In normal Dijkstra if you reach an already visited node with lesser distance you update that node, in this variation you will also update a node if you reach it with same distance but lesser steps.

Comment: Why not just count the steps while traversing?

Comment: Any constraints? how many nodes and edges in the map?

Comment: @unlut thanks for your answer! I'm currently trying to implement it, but I think it should work fine for me. Thanks!

Comment: If you solved the problem please write an answer and accept it please, so other people seeking answer to same question can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved it with adding a new int variable to my Vertex class. It's a step counter, that is being checked before looking at the cost and it's working!